# VBA Type mismatch error when reading value from a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm reading the value from a spreadsheet and adding 1 on the read value using the below code. The error occurs at `ModelNumber = PreviousModel + 1` and it says type mismatch. `LastRowPrevious` shows correct but `PreviousModel` shows empty. Please help. Thanks!

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Public ModelNumber As String
Public PreviousModel As String
Public FinalModelNumber As String
Sub TrackerInput()
Dim ModelDescription As String
Dim LastRowPrevious As String
LastRowPrevious = Worksheets("Model Tracker").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If LastRowPrevious = 2 Then
    ModelNumber = 2
    PreviousModel = 1
Else
    PreviousModel = Cells(LastRowPrevious, 1).Value
    ModelNumber = PreviousModel + 1
End If
MsgBox ("You are creating a new model. Model number is " & ModelNumber)
End Sub
```

Comment: Just FYI, your code will break (or behave erratically) when `Worksheets("Model Tracker")` isn't the `ActiveSheet`, because `Rows` is referring to the active sheet but you're trying to get the last row on the `Model Tracker` sheet. And `Cells(LastRowPrevious, 1)` also refers to the active sheet.

Comment: PLEASE use Option Explict, compile, then define needed variables ... it will relieve stress like nothing you have ever seen :)   Add Dim for PreviousModel and ModelNumber as Integer (or long or double). You may also want to check if the cell is 'empty' (or check if 'IsNumeric'...)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use Excel as a database. FWIW it wasn't meant for this, and you'll inevitably run into the issues associated with using Excel as a database. Only a database ensures referential integrity and consistent ID/numbering of records.

Comment: I had option explicit and all the variables defined. Forgot to include them here. Sorry.

Comment: Why errors will occur when `Worksheets("Model Tracker")` isn't active? Should I change `LastRowPrevious = Worksheets("Model Tracker").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` into `Worksheets("Model Tracker").Activate LastRowPrevious = Active.Cells(Rows.Count, 1),End(xlUp).Row` ?

Comment: Because `Rows.Count` is the number of rows in the active sheet. You want that to be `Worksheets("Model Tracker").Rows.Count` - gets really sloppy, really fast. hence most people would do `With Worksheets("Model Tracker")` and do `LastRowPrevious = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` inside that `With` block (notice the dots).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked perfectly for me:

```
Option Explicit
Public ModelNumber$
Public PreviousModel$
Public FinalModelNumber$
Sub TrackerInput()
    Dim ModelDescription$
    Dim LastRowPrevious$
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRowPrevious = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If LastRowPrevious = 2 Then
            ModelNumber = 2
            PreviousModel = 1
        Else
            PreviousModel = .Cells(LastRowPrevious, 1).Value
            ModelNumber = PreviousModel + 1
        End If
    End With

    Debug.Print ; LastRowPrevious
    Debug.Print ; PreviousModel
    Debug.Print ; ModelNumber
    MsgBox ("You are creating a new model. Model number is " & ModelNumber)
End Sub
```

Noticed I fully referenced the worksheet instead of trying to get VBA to figure out what worksheet im referring too.

Comment: @Mat's Mug was right, I have to stay on that worksheet or put everything in the with. Thank you guys for the help!